# How to avoid interference by Telerik OpenAccess Addin with my Visual Studio 2010 Addin Commandbar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, telerik-open-access

Please tell me how to avoid Telerik OpenAccess ORMs Visual Studio menus' Interferenece with my Addin's menu on under Tools menu option of Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

I am developing a simple Visual Studio Addin for Visual Studio 2010 in C#.

I have Telerik OpenAccess ORM  installed.

### Telerik OpenAccess ORM Version

Its version is:**Telerik-OpenAccess-ORM-2011.3.1129.2**

My plugin creates a command bar and its submenus under Tools Menu of Visual Studio. Please see its structure below:

### Correct Menu Structure:

> Tools
>
> > My Addin Menu
> >
> > > SubMenu 1
> > >
> > > SubMenu 2

When plugin is installed under "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins", On first start everything works fine, and Tools options correctly shows my addin's menu and its submenu.

But if i remove my addin and reinstall again, this is how the situation becomes:

### With OpenAccess ORM

> Tools
>
> > OpenAccess
> >
> > > OpenAccess related sub menu 1
> > >
> > > > > SubMenu1
> > > > >
> > > > > SubMenu2
> >
> > OpenAccess
> >
> > > OpenACcess related sub menu 1
> > >
> > > > OpenAccess related sub menu 2
> > > >         OpenAccess related sub menu 3
> > > >         My Addin Menu
> > > >
> > > > > SubMenu1
> > > > >
> > > > > SubMenu2
> >
> > OpenAccess
> >
> > > OpenACcess related sub menu 1
> > >
> > > > OpenAccess related sub menu 2
> > > >         OpenAccess related sub menu 3>
> > > >         My Addin Menu
> > > >
> > > > > SubMenu1
> > > > >
> > > > > SubMenu2

### PROGNOSIS

If i uninstalled all Telerik Products like "Telerik Rad Controls for Silverlight, WPF, Winforms and Telerik Reporting", My addin menus appear at the right place, no matter waht number of times i install or uninstall y Addin.

### Environment Details

1. Windows 7 ultimate SP1 x64 / Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 x64
2. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 Rel/ Visual Studio Professional SP1
   Rel

### TESTS

1. Presence of Resharper and/or DevXPress tools have no negative impact
   on my addin menu options
2. Presence of telerik ORM interfers with the menu options of my addin

Please note that **i have Resharper and DevXpress controls installed too** and they donot interfere with mhy addin at all.

**I was able to reproduce the same problem on two other Windows 7 based machines which had only Telerik products installed**

Due to company licensing, product idea protection and NDA i may not be able to provide a sample of my addin for testing.

### Code Source

However i am using the same code provided here to create command bars and add to Visual Studio Tools Menu
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/mz2005003.aspx

I am still trying to investigate the problem and trying to determine if it is a bug in Telerik ORM or in my code. The problem better be in my code because, it will be greatly unpleasant to get Telerik ORM updated as the addin is being developed for developers and many of the developers still use the above mentioned version of Telerik Open Access ORM.

### UPDATE

The problem is persistent with Latest (Free) verion of Telerik OpenAccess ORM.

### Telerik_OpenAccess_ORM_Free_Edition_2012_3_1012.zip

Kindly help.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: From the looks of it, this isn't the latest version. OpenAccess went free sometime last year, so you should be able to download the latest version and try it out. 

If that doesn't work, the best way to work around this is to ask the guys in the Telerik Forums. They'll know.

Comment: Thank your for your response and suggestion. I have updated the version of OpenAccess ORM and i am positive that its the latest version and even with the latest version i get the issue. Logically it has to be an issue with the approach! I wonder whats the fault and where?